# Link field programmatically to its taxonomy term page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

In Drupal 7, how can I programmatically add the taxonomy's URL in the view's tpl I have created? This is instead of clicking "Link this field to its taxonomy term page" in the view UI.

Comment: What type of view are we talking about ? Is this a taxonomy term view or a content with a taxonomy relationship attached to it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this in view UI but before using this custom PHP code you have to install views PHP module. you will get is from this link https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php

`$link = url('taxonomy/term/1');`